# ffmpeg parameters to cut video files with Full Re-Encoding

Tags: video, ffmpeg, converters

The following code will be used to trim multiple video files (with different audio or video codecs, or containers etc...). 
The purpose of this code is to cut a video file with ffmpeg as the resulting output (cut) file to contain the same video, audio codecs as the original as using method FULL-RENCODING.
My question is whether there is any error in the current parameters?

Example of used ffmpeg code:

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.vob -ss 00:00:10.000 -strict -2 -t 00:00:10.000 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a? -acodec copy -map 0:s? -scodec copy SSSS.vob
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.mp4 -ss 00:00:10.000 -strict -2 -t 00:00:10.000 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a? -acodec copy -map 0:s? -scodec copy SSSS.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i Sample.mkv -ss 00:00:10.000 -strict -2 -t 00:00:10.000 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a? -acodec copy -map 0:s? -scodec copy SSSS.mkv
```

and others...

Comment: Seems to me that you want to re-encode the video and stream copy everything else. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.000 -t 00:00:20.000 -i input -map 0 -c:a copy -c:s copy -c:d copy output
```

- No need for `-strict -2`. Users often add that for no reason.
- `-ss` as an input option is faster.
- If you want to map all streams use `-map 0` instead of piecemeal `-map` instances.